# NG Build fail in Azure DevOps pipline : Error: Cannot find module '../internal/operators/audit'

Tags: angular, azure-devops

I am trying to configure Azure CI/CD for Angular project

Below is screenshot of azure pipeline :
[image]

Package.json

[image]

Build Project throws following error:

```
2019-05-20T09:19:18.0252202Z > ng build
2019-05-20T09:19:18.0252697Z     ^
2019-05-20T09:19:18.0253091Z 
2019-05-20T09:19:18.0253456Z 
2019-05-20T09:19:18.0254242Z Error: Cannot find module '../internal/operators/audit'
2019-05-20T09:19:18.0254971Z     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
2019-05-20T09:19:18.0255650Z     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
2019-05-20T09:19:18.0256280Z     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
2019-05-20T09:19:18.0257011Z     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
2019-05-20T09:19:18.0257814Z     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\a\1\s\IoTConnectAI\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\node_modules\rxjs\operators\index.js:3:15)
2019-05-20T09:19:18.0258514Z     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
2019-05-20T09:19:18.0259140Z     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
2019-05-20T09:19:18.0259776Z     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
2019-05-20T09:19:18.0260390Z     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
2019-05-20T09:19:18.0264689Z     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
2019-05-20T09:19:18.0265336Z npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-05-20T09:19:18.0265959Z npm ERR! errno 1
2019-05-20T09:19:18.0266569Z npm ERR! sconnectai@0.0.0 build: `ng build`
2019-05-20T09:19:18.0267438Z npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-05-20T09:19:18.0268063Z npm ERR! 
2019-05-20T09:19:18.0268686Z npm ERR! Failed at the sconnectai@0.0.0 build script.
2019-05-20T09:19:18.0270422Z npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-05-20T09:19:18.0271137Z
```

Tried **ng build --prod**

[image]

please help me to fix this

Comment: The error message is *Cannot find module '../internal/operators/audit'*. Did you investigate that error?

Comment: @DanielMann Yes, I have investigated error but not found any solution for this. When i build same code on my local machine its build successfully so i am not sure whats going wrong on azure devops.

Comment: @DanielMann I am getting above error when i add package "rxjs": "^6.5.1" in package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause of the issue trying to build project using npm command
**npm run build**

**ng build** was not working and giving error of no such command because of trying from npm tool.

Add Command line task in Azure DevOps pipeline and build project using ng build
[image]

It works fine and successfully build the project